# Mysql: Добавить столбец к table1, состоящий из GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: связывание-данных, запрос, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица с перечнем фильмов `movies`:

```
| id | name    |
----------------
|  1 | Контакт |
|  2 | Сфера   |
```

Есть таблица с перечнем жанров `genres`:

```
| id | caption      |
---------------------
|  1 | фантастика   |
|  2 | триллер      |
|  3 | драма        |
```

И есть таблица пересечений `links`:

```
| movie_id | genre_id |
|        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        3 |
|        2 |        1 |
|        2 |        2 |
```

Как правильно получить составную таблицу такого вида:

```
| id | name    | genres_captions    |
-------------------------------------
|  1 | Контакт | фантастика,драма   |
|  2 | Сфера   | фантастика,триллер |
```

(Сначала подумал, что можно было бы и не приводить к этому виду и обходиться в случае чего `FIND_IN_SET()`, храня ID жанров прямо в таблице `movies`, но не пошло. Решил, что приведя к нормальному виду все получится, но нет.)

Кроме того, следует сказать, что вся получившаяся таблица будет подвержена фильтрации (на самом деле я пытаюсь реализовать поиск), то есть, в реальности запрос будет похож на:

```
SELECT * FROM (<комбинированная таблица с жанром>) AS `combined`
WHERE
    `name` LIKE "%контакт%"
    OR `name` LIKE "%триллер%"
    OR `genres_captions` LIKE "%контакт%"
    OR `genres_captions` LIKE "%триллер%"
```

Понимаю, что вопрос про объединение нормальных таблиц – из серии студенческих курса 2-го, но я уже часок с ним мучаюсь, прошу помочь. Пробовал в под-под-запросе получать таблицу с `genre_id` WHERE `movie_id` = `movie`.`id`, а уровнем выше – находить названия жанров по полученным `genre_id`, затем их склеивать с помощью `GROUP_CONCAT`, но в под-запросе 2-го уровня почему-то не получалось подставить `movie`.`id` (не доставало).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На работе не на чем свалидировать запрос. Но получилось вот что:

```
SELECT mov.id, 
       mov.name, 
       Group_concat(caption) AS genres_captions 
FROM   movies AS mov 
       LEFT JOIN links AS lin 
              ON ( mov.id = lin.movie_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN genres AS gen 
              ON ( lin.genre_id = gen.id ) 
GROUP  BY id
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Вот поправленный вариант:

    SELECT mov.id, 
           mov.name, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(caption) AS genres_captions 
    FROM   movies AS mov 
           LEFT JOIN links AS lin 
              ON ( mov.id = lin.movie_id ) 
           LEFT JOIN genres AS gen 
              ON ( lin.genre_id = gen.id ) 
    GROUP BY id